# Logstash: Regex matching files without extension

Tags: regex, logstash

I want to exclude files without extension in Logstash config file

I need to do it with a Regex and can't achieve it. The path I'm following is to exclude any file that doesn't contain a dot in the name.

I've read a lot and tried but Logstash keeps eating files I need to exclude from being forwarded to ElasticSearch.

My last try and error:

```
input {
    file {
            type => "exe-data"
            path => "/elastic-data/**/*"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
            codec => plain { charset => "ISO-8859-1" }
            exclude => "*.gz"
            exclude => "*.zip"
            exclude => "^([^.]+)$"
```

Comment: [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-exclude) does not support a regex.

Comment: ok I might use a grok filter but can't imagine how to avoid the file if condition matches

Comment: Your regex is correct, `^[^.]+$` matches a string of 1 or more chars other than `.`

Answer (score 0):

While `exclude` on the file input may not support regexes, you can deal with this in the filter stage.

```
filter {
  if [path] =~ "^/elastic-data/[^.]+$" {
    drop {}
  }

  otherfilter {

  }
}
```

By having a `drop {}` as the first stage in your filtering pipeline, you get a minimal hit from ingesting the dot-less files.

Comment: Take a look at the path in the original post:
`path => "/elastic-data/**/*"`
There is a recursion just after "elastic-data", will your solution cover the recursion here? I can't see how. Might test it anyway in a couple of hours.